# Sum of numeric field is not displaying as a real number in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, format

I have calculated the area of polygons in my map in the Attribute Table with the Field calculator

[image]

This command gives me a new column with the area for each polygon

[image]

Then I go to the "Basic Statistics for numeric fields" option in the Analysis Tools at the vector toolbar.

[image]

Unfortunately the statistics is displayed with the "e" coefficient

[image]

How can I have it as a full number and not in this short version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent some time and figured it out.

I went to the "Measurements" in the  project properties and change the area measurements to square kilometers, so me numbers will be much shorter as the calculate for square meters.
[image]

Then I calculated the area output field type as a "Decimal number (real)" [image]

And when I want back to the "Basic Statistics for numeric fields" the display was as almost as I wanted [image]

Comment: What country has the maximum value? Is that the largest country? You are getting pretty close to the maximum for a integer: 2147483647

Comment: @Vesanto you are right to ask this question there was some kind of mix up with the print screen and I have make it right. To your question: the country is Antarctica with 74760224 Square kilometers